# Dual directional coupler schematic?

Tags: microwave, ads, coupler

I am new to microwaves. I am trying to design a dual directional coupler using ADS software, but researching dual directional coupler isn't working; all that's showing is directional couplers and bi-directional couplers which is not my goal.

I have tried YouTube videos but zero results.

I can't even start imagining the circuitry so I'm stuck at the beginning.

Can please someone help?

Comment: How many ports on your "dual"?

Comment: perhaps this link could be of use? https://nuclearrambo.com/wordpress/home-brewing-simple-antenna-analyzer-part-1/

Comment: this solved the problem of the schematic thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "dual directional coupler"? A directional coupler is a four-port device where one port is the isolated port. In theory, three kinds of directional couplers are possible:

- \$|\alpha| = 0\$: Forward coupler (transversal), Port 2 isolated
- \$|\beta| = 0\$: Backward coupler, Port 3 isolated
- \$|\gamma| = 0\$: Forward coupler (longitudinal), Port 4 isolated

The term "isolated port" refers to the port from which no power comes out when feeding into port 1. Since a directional coupler is a reciprocal component, no output power will appear on another port if power is not fed into port 1.

[image]

In addition to this theoretical point of view, there are various practical realizations. A simple forward branchline coupler (transversal) at 3 GHz, for example, can be simulated in ADS like this:

Schematic:
[image]

Results:
[image]

Depending on your application, design frequency, bandwidth, etc., you might select a different type of practical realization.

Answer (score 1):

The isolated port on a directional coupler couples energy from the reverse direction. Just remove the termination on the isolated port, treat it as the reverse coupled port, and you got a dual directional coupler.

Unfortunately, this method suffers from the following issue: the directivity of the coupler is highly dependent on your coupled port match. An alternative that solves this problem is to stick two directional couplers back to back (facing opposite directions), each with its isolated port properly terminated with a good match.

Comment: thank you for this description. i'll work on it